# How do I fix this? ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be inherited from `kivymd.app.MDApp`

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I just cannot understand why it doesn't, I'm trying to create this simple program but it gives me this error.
my code is:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

class Mainapp(App):
        theme_cls = ThemeManager()

Mainapp().run()
```

**helper.kv**

```
NavigationLayout:

   MDNavigationDrawer:

   ScreenManager:
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

```
class Mainapp(App):
```

to:

```
class Mainapp(MDApp):
```